# argparse: treat unrecognized options as positional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Consider that:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('foo', nargs='+')
p.add_argument('--bar')
p.parse_args(['-baz'])
```

fails with:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: -baz
```

Is there anyway to configure `ArgumentParser` to treat unrecognized options as positional arguments?

In the above example, `p.parse_args(["-baz"])` should return `Namespace(foo=["-baz"])` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'--' is a pseudo arg that tells the parser to treat all following strings as positional.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing

Also look into using `parse_known_args`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing

Comment: I'm aware of '--' thanks - but it looks like `parse_known_args` is my best bet here.  I think if I leave out the `add_argument('foo', nargs='+')` call altogether, then the second element of the tuple result of `parse_known_args` can be used in lieu of the value of `foo`.